# Why GUI should use call_soon_threadsafe() when talking to asyncio loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-asyncio

In a couple of answers (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49959966) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32920184)), when dealing with GUI + asyncio in separate threads, it suggests to use a queue when the asyncio loop needs to communicate with the GUI. However, when the GUI wants to communicate with the asyncio event loop it should use `call_soon_threadsafe()`.

For example, one answer states:

> When the event loop needs to notify the GUI to refresh something, it can use a queue as shown here. On the other hand, if the GUI needs to tell the event loop to do something, it can call call_soon_threadsafe or run_coroutine_threadsafe.

What I don't understand is why can the GUI not also use another Queue rather than `call_soon_threadsafe()`? i.e. can the GUI not put data on a queue for the asyncio loop to get and process? Is it just a design decision or is there some technical reason not to use a queue from GUI to asyncio loop?

Comment: `call_soon_threadsafe` just means "execute this function in the event loop thread". It's totally up to you what the function will do, and putting something into an asyncio queue is a perfectly valid choice. It's not the _only_ choice, however - you might also want to set an event, start executing a coroutine, and so on. But whatever you do, you must do it from the event loop thread, otherwise (e.g. by using `call_soon` instead of `call_soon_threadsafe`) you risk the event loop to get corrupted or fail to notice the new event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no appropriate queue class to use. `asyncio.Queue` isn't safe to interact with from outside the event loop, and `queue.Queue` would block the event loop.

If you want to use a queue anyway, you could use `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe` to call an `asyncio.Queue`'s `put` method.

Comment: Ah, the ```queue.Queue``` blocking the event loop was the key bit for the penny to drop! Thanks.

Comment: @SImpleOne. Queue.get() and Queue.put() block asyncio's event loop. Queue.get_nowait() and Queue.put_nowait() do not. These need to be polled by testing for Queue.empty() or Queue.full()  respectively. If the operation has not completed  then asyncio.sleep() and go back to try putting or getting again.